# How to parse data from large json in Jmeter with Regular expresion or json path extractor

Tags: json, jmeter

I have the following JSON body. How can I parse it to get the values of StudentId, TermID, etc.?

JSON body:

```json
   [ { "Key" : "Results", "ResultsCollection" : [ { "Key" : "IS.S2.SES.FSA.LoadStudentProfile(%27%2751483081%27%27,%20%27%27HCOL%27%27,%27%27JC%27%27,%27%270%27%27)", "Name" : "Josh Josephy-Zack", "LinkURL" : "IS.S2.SES.FSA.LoadStudentProfile(%27%2751483081%27%27,%20%27%27HCOL%27%27,%27%27JC%27%27,%27%270%27%27)", "Title" : "Josh Josephy-Zack", "EnhancedSponsored" : false, "OriginalURL" : "IS.S2.SES.FSA.LoadStudentProfile(%27%2751483081%27%27,%20%27%27HCOL%27%27,%27%27JC%27%27,%27%270%27%27)", "HasActions" : false, "IsPeoplesoft" : false, "SearchKey" : "h0tlbi9WGlr1hZs1AEEhVhF7qlY=", "Sponsored" : false, "Removed" : false, "Description" : "51483081HCOLJC", "Score" : 1, "Modified" : "2022-08-28 22:59:02.000000", "ACAD_CAREER" : "HCOL", "ACAD_PROG" : "JC", "STDNT_CAR_NBR" : "0", "FIRST_NAME" : "Josh", "LAST_NAME" : "Josephy-Zack", "IS_FSA_DESCR_IS_FSA_ACAD_PROG" : "JC", "NAME_DISPLAY" : "Josh Josephy-Zack", "ACAD_LEVEL_BOT" : "30", "IS_FSA_DESCR100_IS_FSA_ACAD_LEVEL" : "Junior", "EMPLID" : "51483081", "IS_SCL_DESCR_IS_SCL_DESCRI" : "Harvard College", "IS_FSA_DESCR_IS_FSA_ACAD_PLAN" : [ "Physics", "Mathematics" ], "PHONE" : "203/645-7134", "ACAD_PROG_DUAL" : "", "EMAIL_ADDR" : [ "test.jjosephyzack-college.harvard.edu@harvard.edu", "test.joshuajosephyzack-gmail.com@harvard.edu" ], "PRIVACY_FLG" : "Y", "FERPA" : "N", "IS_FSA_DESCR100_IS_FSA_ACAD_PROG" : "Joint Concentration", "IS_FSA_DESCR_IS_FSA_HOUSE" : "Quincy House", "IS_FSA_DESCR_HU_FSA_STATUS" : "Enrollment", "IS_SCL_DESCR_IS_SCL_DESCRM" : [ "Physics", "Mathematics" ], "HU_HASH_EMPLID" : "5evPzmXFIpLp8zdDtt5NGTgtAq6VKtbqp09S6SIivMY6", "HU_HASH_FOLDER" : "nZ2DnkQ3gccBTtKpE8MAxU7gabJ4cGdh9O9b7Ow7F846", "IS_FSA_DESCR_HU_FSA_PLN_DPT_DSP" : [ "Physics", "Mathematics" ], "HU_EMPLID_CAREER" : "51483081HCOL", "IS_FSA_PHOTO" : "/Photos/nZ2DnkQ3gccBTtKpE8MAxU7gabJ4cGdh9O9b7Ow7F846/5evPzmXFIpLp8zdDtt5NGTgtAq6VKtbqp09S6SIivMY6.png?ver=764077" }, { "Key" : "IS.S2.SES.FSA.LoadStudentProfile(%27%2791403870%27%27,%20%27%27HCOL%27%27,%27%27JC%27%27,%27%270%27%27)", "Name" : "Kiran Linsuain", "LinkURL" : "IS.S2.SES.FSA.LoadStudentProfile(%27%2791403870%27%27,%20%27%27HCOL%27%27,%27%27JC%27%27,%27%270%27%27)", "Title" : "Kiran Linsuain", "EnhancedSponsored" : false, "OriginalURL" : "IS.S2.SES.FSA.LoadStudentProfile(%27%2791403870%27%27,%20%27%27HCOL%27%27,%27%27JC%27%27,%27%270%27%27)", "HasActions" : false, "IsPeoplesoft" : false, "SearchKey" : "HASgm6RyJebfxiEYSivPt7MM_og=", "Sponsored" : false, "Removed" : false, "Description" : "91403870HCOLJC", "Score" : 1, "Modified" : "2022-08-28 23:47:55.000000", "ACAD_CAREER" : "HCOL", "ACAD_PROG" : "JC", "STDNT_CAR_NBR" : "0", "FIRST_NAME" : "Kiran", "LAST_NAME" : "Linsuain", "IS_FSA_DESCR_IS_FSA_ACAD_PROG" : "JC", "NAME_DISPLAY" : "Kiran Linsuain", "ACAD_LEVEL_BOT" : "30", "IS_FSA_DESCR100_IS_FSA_ACAD_LEVEL" : "Junior", "EMPLID" : "91403870", "IS_SCL_DESCR_IS_SCL_DESCRI" : "Harvard College", "IS_FSA_DESCR_IS_FSA_ACAD_PLAN" : [ "Physics", "Mathematics" ], "PHONE" : "412/926-8923", "ACAD_PROG_DUAL" : "", "EMAIL_ADDR" : [ "test.kiranlinsuain-college.harvard.edu@harvard.edu", "test.kiranlinsuain-gmail.com@harvard.edu" ], "PRIVACY_FLG" : "Y", "FERPA" : "N", "IS_FSA_DESCR100_IS_FSA_ACAD_PROG" : "Joint Concentration", "IS_FSA_DESCR_IS_FSA_HOUSE" : "Leverett House", "IS_FSA_DESCR_HU_FSA_STATUS" : "Enrollment", "IS_SCL_DESCR_IS_SCL_DESCRM" : [ "Physics", "Mathematics" ], "HU_HASH_EMPLID" : "2DPDP7mU8eTwDHduaUwQquBIlSlscOFKr1PraqxInuo6", "HU_HASH_FOLDER" : "SIw3HxekiSltVLRlQ9wDhJpkGdzXP1PBHG3XVbBHnXc6", "IS_FSA_DESCR_HU_FSA_PLN_DPT_DSP" : [ "Physics", "Mathematics" ], "HU_EMPLID_CAREER" : "91403870HCOL", "IS_FSA_PHOTO" : "/Photos/SIw3HxekiSltVLRlQ9wDhJpkGdzXP1PBHG3XVbBHnXc6/2DPDP7mU8eTwDHduaUwQquBIlSlscOFKr1PraqxInuo6.png?ver=749905" } ] }, { "Key" : "Facets", "Facets" : [ ] }, { "Key" : "SearchProperties", "HitCount" : 2, "DocumentCount" : 2, "PageSize" : 999, "PageNumber" : 1, "TotalPages" : 1, "ResultStart" : 1, "ResultEnd" : 2, "SearchText" : "", "SearchQuery" : "", "SearchTextOriginal" : "(HU_EMPLID_CAREER:51483081HCOL | HU_EMPLID_CAREER:91403870HCOL)", "BoostEnabled" : false, "BoostMode" : "", "BoostScoreMode" : "", "BoostExcludeNonBoosted" : "" }, { "Key" : "SignerInfo", "Signers" : [ { "Key" : "51483081", "StudentID" : "51483081", "Srvindreseaon" : "HCOL", "Srvsindicator" : "H01", "SrvcIndDttm" : "2022-08-07 23:03:55.000000", "SignerName" : "Arthur Jaffe", "AuditAction" : "D", "AuditDttm" : "2022-08-25 06:47:05.609115", "IsPrimary" : "Y", "HasComments" : "N", "Denied" : "N" }, { "Key" : "91403870", "StudentID" : "91403870", "Srvindreseaon" : "HCOL", "Srvsindicator" : "H01", "SrvcIndDttm" : "2022-08-07 23:03:46.000000", "SignerName" : "Arthur Jaffe", "AuditAction" : "D", "AuditDttm" : "2022-08-25 09:12:24.620026", "IsPrimary" : "Y", "HasComments" : "N", "Denied" : "N" } ], "TermID" : "2232", "TermDescr" : "2023 Spring", "TermDescrshort" : "2023 Spr" } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor):

StudentId:

> $..Signers[0].StudentID

TermID:

> $..TermID

Configuration would be:

[image: Configuration for TermID]